# jQuery .after() that replaces instead of appends

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following test. You'll notice hi and hello were both added. What I need is for hi to be replaced with hello. As a follow-up question, is there a way to get the value of the .after()?

```js
$("#test").after("hi");
$("#test").after("hello");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=test>TEST</div>
```

Comment: You're inserting a text node after the div. You'd have to remove the text node, and jquery selectors don't select text nodes. You'd be better off using a different strategy than after for this purpose, like inserting/replacing a span or another div.

Comment: Turn it around and use .before()

Comment: What's the point of adding "hi" if you're simply and instantly replacing it?

Comment: Please revise to show a more accurate use case. Good solutions depend on good contextual understanding.

Comment: My use case is highly complex that involved calculation functions that are run multiple times with the change of values in a DevExtreme dxForm, which is why I was just asking for a simplified answer to the ".after()" function. So based on Kevin B's comment and imvain2/j08691's answer. I figured out a solution. I .after() a span with a unique ID, then checked to see if it existed. If so html() a new value, if not, .after the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a span after your div and give it a class name.
Then just reference that class name from after that.
Since you have given it a class name, you can easily get the HTML of that span.

```js
$("#test").after("<span class='subTitle' />");

$(".subTitle").html("HI");
$(".subTitle").html("Hello");

console.log($(".subTitle").html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```